# Crystal Reports, Record display dates from Monday to Friday every Friday

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have created a report with multiple records in Crystal Reports 2016 SP6.

I would like to Format the record {Orders.DeliveryDate} so it only displays days from Monday to Friday.

I have tried formulas like:

```
{Orders.DeliveryDate} = DateAdd ("ww",7,CurrentDate) which just show up blank.
```

The premise of the report is so a company can get their machines prepared on Friday by knowing what orders are coming in on Monday - Friday.

[Image of the records on the report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k73QP.png)

Comment: Please don't post images but include the records as text into your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a Formula that works

```
{Orders.DeliveryDate} >= Maximum(LastFullWeek) + 8 and
{Orders.DeliveryDate} <= Maximum(LastFullWeek) + 14
```